# What is a good UML or ReverseEngineering Language for Visual C++ 6.0?

Tags: visual-c++, uml

What is a good UML or ReverseEngineering Language for Visual C++ 6.0 ?

I have to build upon another guys code that is greater than 50K lines and tons of classes.
He has little to no documentation.  I need to produce a map and see how everything intertwines.

I am looking for software package to read in the project code and produce a map of the classes and showing how things relate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use Poseidon UML (http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumltool/?src=google&kw=UML&mt=b&net=g&plc=&gclid=CNnmsMr9w6sCFQhrgwod9GFy5w).  I also like Rational (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/769.html)

Your attempt to document the C++ may fail as UML has trouble with specific implementations. You may get an approximation.

I also like LePus3 (http://www.lepus.org.uk/) which is not UML but it seems to reverse engineer better.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm interested in this topic too, so did a little search:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140255(v=office.10).aspx